# Is there a way to use the unique values of a count of occurences into column headers pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `df1`.

```
Time        Category
23:05:07    a
23:11:12    b
23:12:15    a
23:16:12    a
```

Another dataframe `df2` has been created returning the count of occurences of each of the unique values in column `category` and into intervals of 5 minutes. Using this code `df2= df1.resample('5T').category.value_counts()`

`df2`

```
Time   Category   Category 
23:05  a          1
23:10  a          1
23:10  b          1
23:15  a          1
```

Is there a way to use the unique values as column headers? Look like:

```
Time   a   b 
23:05  1   0
23:10  1   1
23:15  1   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value_counts` returns multiindex series. So, you just need to work directly on its result by chaining `unstack` to get your desired output.

Since you were able to `resample`, I assume `Time` is your index and it is already in `datetime` or `timedelta` dtype

```
df_final = df1.resample('5T').Category.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

Out[79]:
Category  a  b
Time
23:05:07  1  0
23:10:07  1  1
23:15:07  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work. I renamed your second 'Category' column to 'CatUnique'.

```
df.groupby(['Time','Category'])['CatUnique'].sum().unstack().fillna(0).reset_index()
```